# Is it possible to create a dynamic overlay grid in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis, arcmap

I have a shapefile of multiple polygon features corresponding to geographic regions that vary in area. The task is to create a dynamic grid over each polygon, with the size of the squares for each grid dependent on the area of the polygon, e.g. if area of polygon exceeds a certain threshold then grid square width and height is x metres by x metres. I can use the Grid Index Features tool in ArcMap (v 10.7) to create one grid over a single polygon, so am wondering if this can be extended to loop through multiple polygons, producing the required grid for each polygon. The ultimate aim is to create input for Data Driven Pages to produce a map atlas for each geographic region, including an overview map plus maps for each of the individual grid squares to provide greater detail.

Comment: I think this question would be best asked at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I've added the question to GIS Stack Exchange as suggested.